# Firewalld insert rule before ESTABLISHED

Tags: iptables, firewall, firewalld, firewall-cmd

I want to ban already established connections.

Default iptables rules generated by firewalld

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
```

How to insert rule before `-j ACCEPT` ?

Or how to move INPUT_direct to top?

Or how to remove conntrack rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert an iptables rule with iptables -I parameter
So if you specify
`iptables -I INPUT -j INPUT_direct` 
this rule will be inserted to to top.

If you specify it with a row numer:
`iptables -I INPUT 2 -j INPUT_direct`
it will be inserted as rule in line 2.

In order to move the rule:

1. Delete it first:
   `iptables -D INPUT -j INPUT_direct`
2. Insert it to the top
   `iptables -I INPUT -j INPUT_direct`

Comment: Firewalld removes it after reload

Comment: The order of the rules is correct. First all packet with state ESTABLISHED, RELATED will be allowed, then internal trafic to lo interface and then ports which you would like to open will go in the INPUT_direct chain.

Comment: i want to ban already ESTABLISHED connections

Comment: This has nothing to do with your original question. In order to further help you, could you elaborate why would you would like to do this?

Comment: I have bruteforce attack on udp service (SIP). UDP has no connections by design, but added to conntrack table.

Comment: I would do: iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 5060(for SIP) -j DROP  . The purpose of the mangle table is not packet filtering.

Comment: Question about firewalld - iptables rules will be flushed at restart!

Comment: for DROP i can change table to raw, but i want to be able use REJECT too

Answer (score 0):

As workaround I inserted rule in `raw` (or mangle) table:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 mangle PREROUTING_direct 0 \
  -m set --match-set ipsetname src -j DROP
```

This chain is before INPUT and as i have no FORWARD on this machine - it solves my problem.